# Perl PPM Packages...Cannot connect to http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/package.xml

Tags: xml, perl

I am using Perl to extract pubmed abstracts. I want to use `XML::LibXML` but when i tried to install using ppm install I got the following error

```
  Can't connect to theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/package bad hostname
```

I tried to open through browser but this page cannot load.

Can anybody please help

Answer (score 2):

This repository is either down or gone for good. Use another repository. [PPM::Repositories](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/PPM-Repositories-0.19/Repositories.pm) can set them up for you. Better yet, use `cpan` to install modules:

```
cpan XML::LibXML
```

If you don't have a compiler PPM can get one for you:

```
PPM MinGW
```

Unless you're running a 64bit ActiveState. They don't support 64bit well. See [this chart](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/MinGW/). Better still, move to a sensible Perl distribution like [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/), comes with all the development tools you really need, supports cpan and PPM installation out of the box, proper 32/64 bit builds and stacks of modules already installed.

Comment: I am bound to use ActivePerl unfortunately...is there anyother way to solve this problem . To access this particular Url

Comment: because for even PPM::Repositories its giving the same error downloading kobes packlist failed....500 cant connect to theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/package bad hostname

Comment: Did you read my answer, I tell you another way to do it.

Comment: Yes I tried with cpan too but it diesnt work for me as well

Comment: "doesn't work"? How is anyone supposed to be able to help unless you say what when wrong? I think you need to read the stack overflow posts on how to ask quesitons

Comment: And after running these commands, what do I do to install `mod_perl.so` for my Apache2.4 ?

Comment: @sk001 Are you actually running ActiveState perl on something non windows? If so you need to check their repositories. IIRC you need to pay to access some parts depending on the Perl version. On Linux/Solaris I always roll my own perl and build this stuff from souce

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche I'm running ActiveState Perl on Windows server 2018 R2, with XAMPP (Apache2.4, PHP 5.6)

Comment: @sk001 doesn't XAMPP ship with it's own Perl? Strawberry? That'd make life a whole lot easier. As for AS you'd have to check. If it's not available with PPM you'd need to check with them or another AS repo. See also http://perl.apache.org/download/binaries.html & https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html

Comment: I'm installing OCS Inventory, and it needs mod_perl.so, unavailable in Apache2.4's modules.

Comment: @sk001 it looks as though theory5x no longer resolves to anything. Could be down for a short while, make have gone for good. You could consider building from source: http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1069512